# Why isn't Ember.js seeing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from my server?

Tags: ember.js, cors

My app is an Ember.js front end with a Go API on the server.  I created the Ember app using the FixtureAdapter.  Now that I have the Go API back end I converted it to RESTAdapter.

When I hit my API directly with the browser, I seem to get the appropriate CORS headers back:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT,PATCH,GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Length
```

However, when my Ember.js app hits the API, I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://192.168.59.103:8001/notifications. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.59.103:9000' is therefore not allowed access.`.

I don't know how else to see what's going on between Ember and the API.  I've read [this CORS tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) and everything seems to be okay on the server end.

I included the bit about `x-requested-with` because of another Stack Overflow question suggesting that jQuery requests need something different than plain old JavaScript requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoints also need to respond with CORS headers to OPTIONS requests- those will execute before the actual request to make sure that the request is allowed first.

Comment: Interesting!  Well, I tried it a la `$ curl -v -k -X OPTIONS https://token:@localhost:8001/notifications`.  The CORS headers come through, but the HTTP status code returned is 404.  :-)  I suppose I need to fix that.  (I wonder why OPTIONS request wasn't handled in the original API code.  I grabbed it from a demo from http://0value.com/build-a-restful-API-with-Martini .)

Comment: Most APIs don't respond to OPTIONS requests, but it is a best practice, and a requirement for the REST Adapter. I usually set a single wildcard catchall route that just returns my CORS headers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to be using Nginx as your reverse proxy for your API?  If so, we experienced this same issue.  In our case, the problem was that Nginx returns the correct CORS headers just fine for `HTTP 200 OK` responses, but for any error response, it will fail to add the COR headers and therefore the actual server response gets obscured by the browser complaining that it doesn't have the appropriate CORS headers to render a response.

See https://serverfault.com/a/431580/199943.

Even if you're not using Nginx, try calling your API directly (e.g. using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to avoid the CORS restrictions to see what it's returning.  If your API is returning anything other than an `HTTP 200 OK`, that may be why the CORS headers aren't getting added.

Comment: No Nginx.  Just using Go's http.  Thanks for the tip; I tried Postman and am only getting a 200 back.